# can a power supply with high voltage value and some current be split into multiple small voltages of same current?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, power

For example: if I have a source that can give an output of 10,000 Volts with some unknown current value, now, can i make that 10,000 Volts to 50 (need not be 50 exactly but maybe more than 30) of 200 volts with the same current as previous? If yes can I have any sources for the circuits to build such a system?

This ideology can be used for the **HOUSEHOLD POWER SUPPLY** where this condition can be fruitful for splitting the electricity **INTERNALLY** at home which greatly reduces the **ELECTRICITY BILLS** and the construction of the above said source is still under research

Comment: You should tell us what you wish to do, not how you think it should be done. We do not know why you thing a 'constant current' system will meet your needs (as we do not know what your needs are) BUT it is very likely that a CC system is NOT what you want. Tell us what you are trying to do. ||| 
You should use capital letters where they are required - failure to do so will cause you FAR more problems than you realise. (I know this is true as you would not do it if you knew how much trouble it will cause you).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: _might be_     Yes sir, It would be more appropriate.

Comment: The answer is, yes, there are simple circuits that do just that. They are, for instance, used along marine telecommunications cables which have hundreds of amplifiers placed inside the cable to prevent the signals from deteriorating too much. For household power applications the correct engineering solution uses transformers because all household voltages have to be referenced to the same ground potential, otherwise the circuits would be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a source that can give an output of 10,000 Volts with some unknown current value, now, can I make that 10,000 Volts to 50 numbers(need not be 50 exactly but may be more than 30) of 200 volts with the same current as previously.

Yes, you can.  What you have is effectively a constant current source with a maximum terminal voltage.

Common systems we encounter day to day are usually CV (constant voltage ) and

- We vary power taken by changing the current taken up to some limit.
- An accidental short circuit can cause excessive current to flow.
- An emergency device (eg a fuse) open circuits the connection if current flow is too high.

With a CC (constant current) system

- We vary power taken by changing the load voltage up to some limit.
- An accidental open circuit can cause excessive voltage to occur.
- An emergency device (eg a shoting switch) short circuits open circuits the connection if supplied voltage is dangerously high.

BUT there is a major condition, which may make the system of limited value, depending on the application.  To do this without converters whose outputs are isolated from their inputs, the separate supplies must be in series.

eg to take a smaller example which illustrates the principal.

- Q: Given a 3 amp constant current source
  with a maximum output voltage of 100 Volts DC,
  how can I provide a 50V, 10V and 2 x 20V supplies
  each delivering a constant 3 A.
- A: Provide 4 supplies connected in series
  50V + 10V + 20V + 20V =  100V.

  The 4 supplies are connected in series to the 3A supply
  so that the 3A flows through each of them in turn.

[100V, 3A source]->3A->-[50V, 3A]->3A->-[10V,3A]->3A->-[20, 3A]->3A->-[20, 3A]->3A->- Ground (3A sink).

If any supply is overloaded to try to draw more than 3A the supply voltage will fall until 3A is provided.

If this was part of a 10,000 x 3A_CC supply, if any power supply load tries to aake LESS than 3A, the voltage will rise and rise and rise ... until  3A is supplied.

To turn a supply OFF the output must be short circuited. Open circuiting the output will cause death and destruction as the system tries to supply 3A.